# glfw makefile error: library not found for glfw3

Tags: makefile, glfw

Using makefile, I attempted to link the glfw3 library manually. This is my directory:

```
+root
 +include
  +GLFW
    glfw3.h
    glfw3native.h
 +lib
  +GLFW
    libglfw.3.dylib
    libglfw3.a
 +src
   main.cpp
 Makefile
```

My makefile compiles and builds an executable when I place this in my flags:

```
LDFLAGS = -Llib/GLFW
LDLIBS = -lglfw3 -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit
```

but says error when I modify a little:

```
LDFLAGS = -Llib
LDLIBS = -lGLFW/glfw3 -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit
#error :library not found for -lGLFW/glfw3
```

or this:

```
LDFLAGS = -Llib
LDLIBS = -lglfw3 -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit
#error :library not found for -lglfw3
```

This is quite strange frankly. Some questions to be asked:

Is there a reason why the first is preferred?

Does `-Llib` find all libraries inside the directory `lib`, even if there is another inner directory that contains them?